# How do I configure and lift a Sails.js Project into a Web host as Plesk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, plesk

I rent a server which has `Plesk` as it panel.So, I would like to know how can i configure a Domain with a `Sails.js` Project using the Plesk's tool.

Comment: You may try instructions from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqfMPSS1NAc